# Is there any String Prototype for Setters in JavasScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

In JavaScript, `valueOf` method used to get Primitive Value of Strings.
Is there any method used to set Primitive Value of String.

Comment: `String` primitives and objects are immutable

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken, the `valueOf` method is called to get a primitive value *for an object*. A string already *is* a primitive value, the method will never be called on it.